# Select last non-null value for given partition - Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I have a table with the following structure:

```
date                city cntry  free  occ
2018-08-13 16:30:00 2    12           5
2018-08-13 16:30:00 2    12     0     
2018-08-13 14:30:00 2    12     1     
2018-08-13 11:00:00 2    12     2     
2018-08-12 13:00:00 2    12     1     
2018-08-12 13:00:00 2    12           4
2018-08-12 08:00:00 2    12           3
2018-08-12 08:00:00 2    12     2     
2018-08-10 15:30:00 2    12           4
```

- date is `timestamp without timezone`
- the rest are `numbers`

I want to get the previous non-null value for a given `city_id/country_id` combo, for both the free and occupied:

```
date                city cntry  free  occ
2018-08-13 16:30:00 2    12     0     5
2018-08-13 14:30:00 2    12     1     4
2018-08-13 11:00:00 2    12     2     4
2018-08-12 13:00:00 2    12     1     4
2018-08-12 08:00:00 2    12     2     3
2018-08-10 15:30:00 2    12     1     4
```

- partition is by `city_id, country_id`, order by `date`
- for the first date of each partition, if there is a NULL values, it becomes zero
- for an existing partition, it uses the previous value
- I'd like the ability to filter by city_id and country_id AFTERWARDS

Basically I'm merging two timelines and I want to keep the previous values (free/occupied) for each partition of `<city_id, country_id>`.

I tried playing with window functions to no avail. I can get my data for either free values or occupied values, but not both.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can there be multiple consecutive NULL values? Please *always* disclose your version of Postgres. And ideally a `CREATE TABLE` script defining data types and constraints. It makes it so much easier for us to test.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create your own window function for this. E.g. this example: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_%28aggregate%29 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354094

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `MAX` function with `coalesce` to make it.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   date date,
   city_id int,
   country_id int,
   free int,
   occupied int
);

insert into T values ('2017-01-01',2,3,null, 2);
insert into T values ('2017-01-02',2,3,4, null);
insert into T values ('2017-01-02',2,3,null, 5);
insert into T values ('2017-01-04',3,4,2, null);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
  date,
  city_id,
  country_id,
  coalesce(MAX(free),0) free  ,
  coalesce(MAX(occupied),0) occupied
FROM T
GROUP BY date,city_id,country_id
order by date;

| date                     | city_id | country_id | free | occupied |
| ------------------------ | ------- | ---------- | ---- | -------- |
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2       | 3          | 0    | 2        |
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 2       | 3          | 4    | 5        |
| 2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z | 3       | 4          | 2    | 0        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bF788aBCfMULffqQnx2XKn/0)

Comment: Sorry, I had some typos in my example. I updated it. Consequently, MAX won't work because I need to get the previous value which has a different date - it won't fall on the same bucket used by the group by.